# Advice needed for excel formula

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I am trying some formulas to incorporate into my excel book. This is is what I need to happen.
A1              A2            Priority
Start date     End date       variable (Low, Medium, High)

If `A1` is between 60 to 120 days, it returns "Low".

If `A1` is between 30 to 59 days, it returns "Medium".

If `A1` is between 0 to 29 days, it returns "High".

If none of the above conditions are met, it returns an empty string ("N/A").

The formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1-A2>=60, A1-A2<=120), "Low", IF(AND(A1-A2>=30, A1-A2<=59), "Medium", IF(AND(A1-A2>=0, A1-A2<=29), "High", "N/A")))
```

or

```
=IF(AND(A2>=60, A2<=120), "Low", IF(AND(A2>=30, A2<=59), "Medium", IF(A2>A1, "High", "N/A")))
```

As a result I either get "HIGH" only or N/A when a date is inputed.
What am I doing wrong?

If `A1` is between 60 to 120 days, it returns "Low".

If `A1` is between 30 to 59 days, it returns "Medium".

If `A1` is between 0 to 29 days, it returns "High".

If none of the above conditions are met, it returns an empty string ("N/A").

The formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1-A2>=60, A1-A2<=120), "Low", IF(AND(A1-A2>=30, A1-A2<=59), "Medium", IF(AND(A1-A2>=0, A1-A2<=29), "High", "N/A")))
```

or

```
=IF(AND(A2>=60, A2<=120), "Low", IF(AND(A2>=30, A2<=59), "Medium", IF(A2>A1, "High", "N/A")))
```

As a result I either get "HIGH" only or N/A when a date is inputed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only need to check one condition for each level because Excel will return the value from the first boolean statement that returns `TRUE`. For example `=IF(A1-A2 < 30, "High", if(A1-A2 < 60, "Medium",....))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the range, just the limit. The [Let Function](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-much-benefit-does-excels-new-let-function-offer-steven-rider/) might help simplify this bit and some coding indentation

```
=Let(zNumber,A1-A2,zOther,"N/A",
      iferror(
            if(zNumber>=0,
                 if(zNumber<30,"High",
                 if(zNumber<60,"Medium",
                 if(zNumber<=120,"Low",zOther))),
               zOther),
          zOther))
```

Comment: Function is not unable to be utilize for the Enterprise subscription.